# How do you make mulitple buttons call the same function when I don't know the button names?

Tags: javascript, .net, html, model-view-controller

I have a stored procedure that will return a result set with n amount of columns (the stored proc's logic determines the columns to be returned) which I use to build a "grid" on they fly. To do this I use a DataTable that I enumerate through at run time to build the DataColumns dynamically:

```
             <table>
                <thead>
                    <% foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in ((System.Data.DataTable)Model).Columns)
                       { %>
                    <th>
                        <%: column.Caption %>
                        <input id="Image1" type="image" src="../Content/theme/images/arrowhead-down.jpg" width="9px" height="5px"/></th>
                    </th>
                    <%}%>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <%
            foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in ((System.Data.DataTable)Model).Rows)
            {%>
                    <tr>
                        <% foreach (var column in row.ItemArray)
                           { %>
                        <td>
                            <%: column.ToString() %>
                        </td>
                        <%}%>
                    </tr>
                    <%
            }
                    %>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

The input of type image (button) will be included for each new column element. Essentially that button will allow for the column to be hidden using some scripting:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Image1').click(function () {
                $('td:nth-child(3),th:nth-child(3)').hide();
            });
        });
```

So my question is this, how can I have each of the newly created buttons call the same function regardless of the name of the button (since I won't know how many buttons will be created or their names)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give them all the same CSS class name. Avoid hooking up JavaScript to IDs when using .NET, it likes to hog them for itself.

Then you can use:

```
$('.buttonClassOfYourChoice').click(function() {
      ....common click code...
})
```

"this" will refer to the button that was clicked:

```
$('.buttonClassOfYourChoice').click(function() {
     alert($(this).html())
})
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  It's people like you why I keep coming back to this site, thank you sir!